# How to apply own function using lapply?

Tags: r, replace, lapply

I have created a custom function to replace values with NA to understand how functions work in R:

```
replacewithna <- function(x) {
  if(x == -99) {
    return(NA)
  }
  else {
    return(x)
  }
}
```

I have a dataframe with several columns and values which contain "-99" in certain elements and want to apply the custom function I created to each element. I have been able to do this with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(survey2)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(survey2)) {
    survey2[i,j] <- replacewithna2(survey2[i,j], NA)
  }
}
```

However, I can't do the same with a lapply. How can I use my replace function with a function from the apply family like so:

```
survey1 <- lapply(survey1, replacewithna)
```

Currently I have the following error: "**Error in if (x == -99) { : the condition has length > 1**"

Comment: You need `ifelse` not `if … else …`.

Comment: @Limey yes that would be the R solution. But I think the question is a different one. I think `survey1` might not be a list. lapply can work with vector inputs but not in the way it is used in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a vectorized version of your function with `ifelse` or, like below, with `is.na<-`.

```
replacewithna <- function(x) {
  is.na(x) <- x == -99
  x
}
```

---

With `ifelse` it is a one-liner:

```
replacewithna <- function(x) ifelse(x == -99, NA, x)
```

---

## Note

With both functions, if `survey1` or `survey2` are data.frames, the correct way of `lapply`ing the function and keep the dimensions, the tabular format, is

```
survey1[] <- lapply(survey1, replacewithna)
```

The square parenthesis are very important.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can also use `sapply` (which returns a vector or a matrix, and might be more appropriate here) with `replace`:

```r
sapply(survey2, function(x) replace(x, x == -99, NA))
```